# Opening Files with Filepath Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

Is it possible to open all types of files from excel vba with just the file path? Right now I can open workbooks with the simple:

```
Workbooks.Open myDestFilePath
```

but what if myDestFilePath is really a .pptx file or whatever else?

Comment: You can use `Shell()` to open any document in its default application (assuming there's an existing file type association for that kind of file).

Comment: http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbafoldersfileopen or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely use Excel VBA to automate other apps, but you need to use the correct application object for the task.  If you're trying to open PowerPoint files, you will need to use PowerPoint to do it.  Here's a crude example:

```
'remember to add the powerpoint object library (Tools->References)
Sub OpenPPTFile()
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("filename.pptx")

    'here you can add code to have powerpoint do all kinds of nifty things to your file

    pptPres.Close

    pptApp.Quit

    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

So if your question is "Can I use Excel to open files created by other apps", the short answer is no.  However, if the question is "Can I use Excel VBA to automate other applications to perform operations on non-Excel files?" the answer is yes.

Comment: Well the pptx file is already created... I just want to open it after the user inputs information... Then I find the file path. When I have the file path I want to open the document that's in that location.

Comment: I could be opening something other than a powerpoint, perhaps a word doc or some other CAD software document

Comment: Generally speaking you'll be restricted to Office documents if you'll be doing this from within VBA (unless a VBA automation library has been provided to you for that particular app).  If I may ask, what will you be doing to the files once you open them?

Comment: well i have the files saved in a location and their paths saved in an access database... Once they open, they just open up and then you close it, you go back to the original tool.

Answer (score 2):

To use internal calls, without an API. I haven't found much that

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "FilePath"
```

Won't open

For example:

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink  "D:\My documents\Movie.mov"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ShellExecute VB function. Just declare de API header and you can "call" a file directly to open it in associated application. Here is an example code:

http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/usando-a-funcao-shellexecute-no-vba

Sorry about the link, but I am writing this answer from my iPad, and its terrible to format code here. :(